# How to get the title of the webpage that the webview is currently holding?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, visual-studio-2017

I am trying to get the title of my webview, so I can store it in my database as a string. But I can't find a way to do so.

I tried to use `mwebview.Title`, but it's giving me the same result as the URL sometimes.

Comment: Are you checking the title in the `OnPageFinished` override?

Comment: I applied what you just say . it's working but is there a way that I can get the right title using `onPageStarted` override? @SushiHangover

Comment: I do not know about that as due to the way various pages can set the title (html tags and javascript), you really do not know when the document is done being parsed or updated via javascript until the OnPageFinished. You could "try" to grab it as soon as possible and later check to see if it is different in the OnPageFinished and update your database if needed..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a full example I put together using the OnPageFinished override in a custom WebViewClient.

**WebViewCustomActivity.cs**

```
using System;
using Android.App;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Webkit;

namespace XamdroidMaster.Activities {

    [Activity(Label = "Custom WebViewClient", MainLauncher = true)]
    public class WebViewCustomActivity : Activity {

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.WebView);
            WebView wv = FindViewById<WebView>(Resource.Id.webviewMain);

            CustomWebViewClient customWebViewClient = new CustomWebViewClient();
            customWebViewClient.OnPageLoaded += CustomWebViewClient_OnPageLoaded;

            wv.SetWebViewClient(customWebViewClient);
            wv.LoadUrl("https://www.stackoverflow.com");
        }

        private void CustomWebViewClient_OnPageLoaded(object sender, string sTitle) {
            Android.Util.Log.Info("MyApp", $"OnPageLoaded Fired - Page Title = {sTitle}");
        }

    }

    public class CustomWebViewClient : WebViewClient {

        public event EventHandler<string> OnPageLoaded;

        public override void OnPageFinished(WebView view, string url) {
            OnPageLoaded?.Invoke(this, view.Title);
        }

    }

}
```

**WebView.axml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/WebView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent">
    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webviewMain"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#FFFFFF" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks but I have a question . when I load twitter on the webview It enters the `onPageLoaded` Function more than once sometimes . Is there a way to stop that? @Robert Bruce

Comment: I tested it with my Twitter account and I wasn't able to reproduce what you're seeing.  If there's a specific Twitter URL that does this, please provide the URL so I can test.  In any case, you could put a boolean flag in the OnPageLoaded method to suppress subsequent calls after the first was raised.